# Discord.js Can't send message to this user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

If I have this error it will send a message embed and which shows a picture about how to turn on direct messages.

but I don't know how to snipped code and send this message

```js
if (error.code === 50007){
  message.channel.send(Embedcantchat);
}
```

Error source

```js
reason: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at C:\Users\nawap\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\bot all\nirtogiven\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:79:15
    at C:\Users\nawap\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\bot all\nirtogiven\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  name: 'DiscordAPIError',
  message: 'Cannot send messages to this user',
  path: '/api/v7/channels/720870400808190013/messages',
  code: 50007,
  method: 'POST'
}
```

Comment: The user has DMs disabled from anyone other than friends. The 'newbie' is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the user has turned off DMs for a certain server, so members in that server will not be able to DM them. You can set this when you click the server name -> Privacy Settings

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to send the message on an error code, you should use a try/catch, such as the one below:

```js
try {
   // message to send the user
}
catch (error) {
   message.channel.send(Embedcantchat);
   // other error handling
}
```

If an error is caught while trying to send the message, then it will automatically send `Embedcantchat`, assuming that it is defined.